# How to overcome "Output of image computation is too large" error

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, random-forest

Does anyone know how to avoid the error of "Output of image computation is too large" in supervised classification using RF? I even tried up to 16 tilescale but it still does not work. Noted that, I need all chosen bands for my classification and I did add the needed filter to my image collection.

Here is the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7789dc1ae25c4006f6cfd1bfa6acaafa

```
var coll1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-05-01', '2020-05-15')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-05-16', '2020-05-31')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll3 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-06-15')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll4 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-06-16', '2020-06-30')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll5 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll6 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-07-16', '2020-07-31')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll7 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-08-01', '2020-08-15')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-08-16', '2020-08-31')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll9 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
var coll10 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2020-09-16', '2020-09-30')
  .filterBounds(ROI)

print(coll1)
Map.centerObject(ROI, 10)

var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

var withNDVI1 = coll1.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI2 = coll2.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI3 = coll3.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI4 = coll4.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI5 = coll5.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI6 = coll6.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI7 = coll7.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI8 = coll8.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI9 = coll9.map(addNDVI)
var withNDVI10 = coll10.map(addNDVI)


var with_ndwi1 = withNDVI1.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi2 = withNDVI2.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi3 = withNDVI3.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi4 = withNDVI4.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi5 = withNDVI5.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi6 = withNDVI6.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi7 = withNDVI7.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi8 = withNDVI8.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi9 = withNDVI9.map(addNDWI)
var with_ndwi10 = withNDVI10.map(addNDWI)

print(with_ndwi1, 'with_ndwi1')

var image1 = with_ndwi1.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_1', 'B3_1', 'B4_1', 'B8_1', 'B11_1', 'B12_1', 'NDVI_1', 'NDWI_1'])
var image2 = with_ndwi2.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_2', 'B3_2', 'B4_2', 'B8_2', 'B11_2', 'B12_2', 'NDVI_2', 'NDWI_2'])
var image3 = with_ndwi3.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_3', 'B3_3', 'B4_3', 'B8_3', 'B11_3', 'B12_3', 'NDVI_3', 'NDWI_3'])
var image4 = with_ndwi4.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_4', 'B3_4', 'B4_4', 'B8_4', 'B11_4', 'B12_4', 'NDVI_4', 'NDWI_4'])
var image5 = with_ndwi5.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_5', 'B3_5', 'B4_5', 'B8_5', 'B11_5', 'B12_5', 'NDVI_5', 'NDWI_5'])
var image6 = with_ndwi6.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_6', 'B3_6', 'B4_6', 'B8_6', 'B11_6', 'B12_6', 'NDVI_6', 'NDWI_6'])
var image7 = with_ndwi7.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_7', 'B3_7', 'B4_7', 'B8_7', 'B11_7', 'B12_7', 'NDVI_7', 'NDWI_7'])
var image8 = with_ndwi8.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_8', 'B3_8', 'B4_8', 'B8_8', 'B11_8', 'B12_8', 'NDVI_8', 'NDWI_8'])
var image9 = with_ndwi9.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_9', 'B3_9', 'B4_9', 'B8_9', 'B11_9', 'B12_9', 'NDVI_9', 'NDWI_9'])
var image10 = with_ndwi10.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI']).mean().rename(['B2_10', 'B3_10', 'B4_10', 'B8_10', 'B11_10', 'B12_10', 'NDVI_10', 'NDWI_10'])

///Creating a stacked image with 30m resolution as my training data///
var stacked = image1.addBands([image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10]).clip(ROI).reproject('EPSG:32636', null, 30)
print(stacked, 'stacked')

Map.addLayer(stacked, vis, 'Stacked')

Map.addLayer(RICE, {}, 'rice', false)
Map.addLayer(MAIZE, {}, 'maize', false)

var rice = RICE.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Feature(feature).set('class', 0)
})
var maize = MAIZE.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Feature(feature).set('class', 1)
})

var sample = rice.merge(maize)

// Generate 5000 random pt sample
var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: sample,
  points: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})
// Pick up the class of each random point
var referenceData = ee.Join.saveFirst('polygon')
  .apply({
    primary: randomPoints, 
    secondary: sample, 
    condition: ee.Filter.intersects({leftField: '.geo', rightField: '.geo'})
  })
  .map(function (feature) {
    var polygon = ee.Feature(feature.get('polygon'))
    return feature
      .copyProperties(polygon)
  })

// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: referenceData,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30,
  
  tileScale: 16,
  
})

//print(training)
Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample')
Map.centerObject(training, 10)


var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(128)
                  .train({
                    features:training , 
                    classProperty: 'class'
                    
                  });

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');
Map.addLayer(classified,
        {min: 0, max:1 , palette: ['yellow','green']},
           'classification',false);
```

Comment: One way to fix this error is to reduce the size of the input image collection by using additional filters, such as .filterMetadata() or .filter(), to select a smaller set of images to work with.

Another approach is to simplify the computation itself by reducing the number of bands being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using reproject in this script at all.  Using it early on in your script will cause each output tile to need too many input tiles and you get the 'too large' error even with a giant tileScale.  If you want to see what the final image will look like in a given projection, then use it at the end, inside the Map.addLayer call.  But, you shouldn't use it during computation at all.

Also, your code can be greatly simplified if you just map over a set of dates instead of repeating everything 10 times.  You also don't need to join the randomPoints with the polygons, you can simply turn the polygons into a raster layer and sample it with other layers.  If you're sampling points, it's better to use ReduceRegions, so the geometries dont have to be recomputed.

Your result doesn't look very good though, I think because your training data is grossly imbalanced with about 4800 vs 170 points.  Balancing it out, seems to produce a better result (78% accuracy)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7fa60c7271cf2ce12bc6845924b696ce

```
var dates = [
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-01', '2020-05-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-05-16', '2020-05-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-01', '2020-06-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-06-16', '2020-06-30'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-01', '2020-07-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-07-16', '2020-07-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-01', '2020-08-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-08-16', '2020-08-31'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-01', '2020-09-15'),
  ee.DateRange('2020-09-16', '2020-09-30')
]

var addNDVI = function(img) {
  var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
  return img.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDWI = function(img) {
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
}

var list = dates.map(function(range) {
  return ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
      .filterDate(ee.DateRange(range))
      .filterBounds(ROI)
      .map(addNDVI)
      .map(addNDWI)
      .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'])
      .mean()
      .rename(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDWI'])
})


var stacked = ee.ImageCollection(list).toBands()
Map.addLayer(stacked, {bands: ["3_NDVI", "5_NDVI", "8_NDVI"]}, 'Stacked', false)

Map.addLayer(RICE, {color: 'yellow'}, 'rice', false)
Map.addLayer(MAIZE, {color: 'green'}, 'maize', false)

// Generate 5000 random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: RICE,
  points: 2500,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})
var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: MAIZE,
  points: 2500,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 1
})

// Paint the reference data into an image so we can sample it.
var referenceData = ee.Image().byte().paint(RICE, 0).paint(MAIZE, 1).rename("class")

// Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.addBands(referenceData).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: random1.merge(random2),
  // Set the scale to get Landsat pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:32636',
  tileScale: 4
})

// How balanced are the training data?
print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"]))
Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample')

// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("class"))
)

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(128)
  .train({
    features: trainingNoNulls.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.8"),
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),
  })

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified')

Map.addLayer(classified.reproject('EPSG:32636', null, 30), {
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: ['yellow', 'green']
  },
  'classification', true)

print(trainingNoNulls
    .randomColumn()
    .filter("random >= 0.8")
    .classify(classifier, "Classified")
    .errorMatrix("class", "Classified")
    .accuracy())
```

Comment: Dear @Noel Gorelick, thank you so much for your explanation. This is my first script so I am still missing a lot in GEE. If you can give me a little elaboration about the imbalance of the training data? what are those numbers representing(4800 vs 170)?!

Comment: even after using the code you provided, the Output of image computation is too large. Did it work with you?

Comment: If you're zoomed out, it's going to fail (because there's a reproject on the end).  Take that part off or don't zoom out.